# GET request return value as error instead of success

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, rest-api, errors, json

I am trying to send response back to ajax request in js by using REST API.

send request from ajax to server is okay and its processing okay.
But to send the response from server to ajax, the ajax receive it as "error" instead of "success".

My ajax in js

[image]

My REST API

[image]

I have tried wp_send_json, json_encode, wp_send_json_success, but results are still the same.

This is what I have in Error from ajax
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 252 you are using `print_r()` inside your code, which is printing out an error message before the proper response, so your response is not valid JSON anymore.

If, as it appears, you want to include the output of `print_r()` in your error log, and not include it in the response, you need to set the second argument so that the value of `print_r()` is *returned*, and not printed:

```
error_log( "get_detail =" . print_r( $data, true ) );
```

Comment: thank you. did not expect that to be the problem.